# Printing Form (on current record)

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, printing

I have a form that computes a very extensive calculation based on inputs which are all saved in a table (declared by Control Source) by a unique identifier.

I export this data into Excel and reformat with a macro. I lose the formatting of the form.

I found that with the form active, I can print this form. The print includes multiple form copies for each record in the table and I do not see this being very user friendly.

I investigated online and see the typical workaround would be to print the unique record based on a report, though I would again lose the layout of the form.

**My question would be**, if I create a copy of the table I am storing my data in (as to capture all columns I am currently using on the original table) and maybe even the form I desire to print, could I have an on-click procedure that would save only the current record and all its inputs to the "PrintTable", and be able to print only the current record, then after it prints clear the table of any records?

Answer (score 1):

Providing answer as unable to comment.

Can you not recreate the form as a report?  Forms are not designed to be printed, however Reports are specifically designed for this purpose.  And you can pass through criteria onto a report. And have virtually the same sort of design as you can put on a form.

Creating a duplicate table just to overcome the issue you are facing flies in the face of normalisation techniques, and should absolutely be avoided at all costs.

Comment: This is a something I will have to check out, I have never really dabbled with reports. Thank you for your response!